# Unity3d. NewInputSystem. TouchSimulation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a new input system with click simulation. Touch.delta, if it is less than some value (as I understand it, less than 1.8), then it turns to zero and the Touch.phase switches to "Stationary".

How can this value be adjusted?
Thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch;
using Touch = UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch;
using InputTouchPhase = UnityEngine.InputSystem.TouchPhase;

sealed class InputSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnEnable() 
    {
        EnhancedTouchSupport.Enable();
        TouchSimulation.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        EnhancedTouchSupport.Disable();
        TouchSimulation.Disable();
    }

    void Update(IEcsSystems systems)
    {
        if (Touch.activeTouches.Count == 0) return;
        var activeTouch = Touch.activeTouches[0];

        var touchPosition = Vector2.zero;
        var delta = Vector2.zero; // !!!

        var phase = activeTouch.phase;
        if (phase == InputTouchPhase.Began)
        {
            delta = Vector3.zero;
            touchPosition = activeTouch.screenPosition;
            return;
        }

        if (phase == InputTouchPhase.Ended || phase == InputTouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            delta = Vector3.zero;
            touchPosition = activeTouch.screenPosition;
            return;
        }

        if (phase == InputTouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            delta = activeTouch.delta;
            touchPosition = activeTouch.screenPosition;
            return;
        }
        else if (phase == InputTouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            delta = Vector3.zero;
            touchPosition = activeTouch.screenPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

In the game, a situation often occurs that you need to slowly move your finger and NewInputSystem shows the value of Touch.delta, the minimum value or zero.

[Quick finger movement (Console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKGtq.png)

[Slow finger movement (Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TeX1.png)

Comment: This is confusing. If you don’t move your finger, the delta will be zero, as you’d expect. What is it you DO expect the delta to be when you don’t move your finger?

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec finger moves but slowly